# Accessing an object in a moved-from state

Tags: c++

Let's say I have a class that manages a resource. Every method has a precondition that must be satisfied: the managed resource must be in a valid state (same way as `unique_ptr` with its `operator*` and `operator->`), and if the object is in a moved-from state, that precondition is not satisfied. For cases where I'm accessing a moved-from object (either accidentally or deliberately for whatever reason), this raises the following questions:

- Is it good design to check (assert) if the precondition is satisfied at the beginning of every method?
- If yes, how exactly would it be good design to address the issue in case it is not? Perhaps throw an exception or something? (I understand this is an opinion-based question)

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "valid state"? Is this an expensive operation to perform, or is it just checking a flag? Usually invalid cases in C++ throw an exception. There's really no other way to refuse to do something that's requested.

Comment: Yes, in idiomatic C++ you `assert` preconditions. These assertions become no-op in a release build.

Comment: A good design is use something like design by contract and static verification. Neither are available in C++.

Comment: I say : no, it isn't. Your code will become a horrible mess of if-then-else instructions of which most else-cases never occur. But you can and should write the public part of your code so that it becomes hard to fail the preconditions, and that they are documented well.

Comment: the caller should make sure preconditions are met. Methods checking their precondition is unnecessary overhead

Comment: @tadman Tbh in my case, that "resource" is really just an int that is supposed to be an ID for a C API, and whether it's valid or not is literally determined by its value (0 == invalid), so I guess it's like checking a flag, nothing expensive. The reason I'm still asking this however, is because I can't seem to find much about safety measures for accessing a moved-from object in general. Everyone just goes "undefined behaviour" or "just don't use a moved-from object". Hence the question: do I throw an exception in such case or just document it as a mistake and call it a day?

Comment: What do you mean by "moved from" specifically? Why not just pop an exception the instant something gets moved instead of tracking down cases where that moved object is used? Even better, prevent moving in the first place so you get compile errors.

Answer (score 0):

In C++, it is usually a good idea to use `assert` from `<cassert>` header to make sure some condition is met, and it has zero overhead in release builds. I don't think throwing is a particularly good idea here, but it is nevertheless an option with its own trade-offs. Throwing makes it harder to write exception-safe code and it makes the condition-check mandatory. I'd say, `assert` it, and also document it that those preconditions shall be met. `std::vector::operator[]` does that on many implementations to check for out-of-bound access in debug mode, for instance.

I just want to make clear that, "moved from" objects, generally, should have a valid state. Users can't make any assumptions about its state or value, but they should be able to reassign or reuse that object.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it good design to check (assert) if the precondition is satisfied at the beginning of every method?

If you can statically assert on it then yes. During runtime no. Consider a caller that has code like this

```
for (int i=0; i<100000;++i) {
    foo.bar();
}
```

Checking the precondition on every iteration is a waste of resources when the condition does not change.

> If yes, how exactly would it be good design to address the issue in case it is not? Perhaps throw an exception or something? (I understand this is an opinion-based question)

That depends on how nice you want to be to the caller. One valid choice is to clearly state the preconditions and if a caller violates them then they are on their own. Compare to eg `std::vector::operator[]`: You want to pass an out-of-bounds index? No problem (from point of view of the operator), undefined behaviour is what you get (a real problem from your point of view). You cannot guarantee well defined behaviour in all situations, especially when the caller didn't care about your preconditions. In some cases you might be able to throw an exception, but that depends on details.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it good design to check (assert) if the precondition is satisfied at the beginning of every method?

Like most things in programming, it is a tradeoff. What is good depends on whether you value more what you gain compared to what you lose.

What you lose in the trade is performance: Not performing a check is at least as fast, and usually faster than performing it. Whether this loss of efficiency is significant depends on the use case. Within the hot path of a CPU bound algorithm: It may be. In a code dealing with network communication: Probably not. To find out whether the difference is significant, you need to measure.

> how exactly would it be good design to address the issue in case it is not?

There are several ways of communicating an error in C++:

- Simplest form is to abort the program. The advantage is that there won't be unknown side effects such as security holes due to undefined behaviour. This is a decent choice when the program would have no way of recovering... but how would you as the implementer of the class know whether the user of the class can recover?
- The standard `assert` macro falls into the same category of terminating the program, but the check is typically enabled only in testing and disabled in release mode which may leave the program vulnerable to exploits.
- Exceptions are a convenient way to either let the client code choose whether they would like to recover from it (`try` - `catch`) or let the program terminate safely. Pre / Post condition violations are typically exceptional cases where an exception is appropriate.
- Use a traditional C style error code. This will force the client to write their own error handling code to avoid potential UB.

Each way has their own advantages and disadvantages. You should choose according to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I will also use assertion-like solution to check preconditions in that code. But instead using bare `assert`, I will use some compiler-specific magick to optimize likely/unlikely cases, like it is done in [Microsoft's GSL library](https://github.com/microsoft/GSL/blob/master/include/gsl/gsl_assert).

You have there `GSL_LIKELY`, `GSL_UNLIKELY` and `GSL_ASSUME` macros and `Expects`, `Ensures` constructs. They are better than normal `assert` because based on them compiler may perform better code optimization and profile assembly against likely/unlikely branches.

Also, what is very cool, you can tune config of GSL and decide, what to do on failed condition: throw, terminate or just nothing. This way you can easily test different behaviors without modifying whole codebase. All you need is to just change some compile definitions.

And another useful thing: using them is more concise. In my opinion `Expects(m_data != nullptr)` is more readable than `assert(m_data != nullptr)`.